# Rewrite all URL requests to https://www.example.com/$1

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two domains, example.com and example.co.uk, that use the same application on my server.

I would like to rewrite the address of the URL depending on what the user types in. The only URLs I want are `https://www.example.com` and `https://www.example.co.uk`

In my `.htaccess` file I have the following:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If I goto `http://www.example.com` it doesn't add the `https`, if I goto `http://example.com` it does. What is the best way of making the ReWriteCond match the www url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your 2 rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# add www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [L,NE,R=301]

# turn on HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [L,NE,R=301]
```

These 2 rules will take care of both of your domains.

Comment: We also required this condition `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https` as the connection was through a load balancer and was resulting in a redirect loop when hitting `https://www.example.com`

Comment: Ah good point, I didn't know about the presence of load balancer.